# Possible to fire a weekly trigger immediately then on a weekly basis?

Tags: quartz.net

I am wondering if it is possible to use weekly trigger to fire once and then go to a weekly schedule

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeWeeklyTrigger(
   "TriggerName",
   dayOfweek, 
   timeOfDay.Hours,
   timeOfDay.Minutes);
```

So I basically want when my service first starts my trigger to fire and run it's job. After that I want it to work on a weekly basis based on user settings(So maybe after first run a user set it to Monday 5:00am).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple triggers associated with one job. One would fire immediately and only once and the other will fire weekly:

```
var jobDetail = new JobDetail("MyJob", "MyGroup", typeof(T));

// run in ten seconds, only once.
var once = new SimpleTrigger("Once",
                             null,
                             DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10),
                             null,
                             0,
                             TimeSpan.Zero); 

// run weekly, start in 5 minutes to give 'once' trigger some time to run
Trigger weekly = TriggerUtils.MakeWeeklyTrigger(
    "Weekly", 
    dayOfweek, 
    timeOfDay.Hours, 
    timeOfDay.Minutes);
weekly.StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

once.JobName = jobDetail.Name;
weekly.JobGroup = jobDetail.Group;
once.JobName = jobDetail.Name;
weekly.JobGroup = jobDetail.Group;

_quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, once);
_quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(weekly);
```

Or you can schedule immediate trigger and when it fires reschedule to weekly:

```
private static volatile Boolean firstRun = false;

public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
    if(firstRun) {
        Trigger weekly = TriggerUtils.MakeWeeklyTrigger(
            "Weekly", 
            dayOfweek, 
            timeOfDay.Hours, 
            timeOfDay.Minutes);

        context.Scheduler.RescheduleJob("Once", "MyGroup", weekly);
        firstRun = false;
    }
}
```

Another option is to just run your code on start up without involving Quartz. Just use ThreadPool. And then let Quartz handle weekly schedule only. This is possible if your code does not depend on Quartz which might be a good idea in general.

Comment: Ok just thought there might be a way without making 2 triggers. When I was testing the once trigger out I found it actually ran twice so I did like they did in once of there examples.

Comment: @chobo2: the repeat time parameter in the answer is equal to 1. Did it fire more than once? Or was it another trigger? What example were you using?

Comment: @ Dmitry - It was the same trigger as each had the same name. This is what I used from the quartz documentation - SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger("myTrigger",
                                          null,
                                          DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10),
                                          null,
                                          0,
                                          TimeSpan.Zero);